# Replace specific characters in excel with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I've got the following code in vba:
[Vba code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUX0E.png)

I would like to find and replace these values in my row.
For example I want to replace 36 to +36 if it's my first two character,but it's just not working,it's replaces the characters in the middle.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, first you change 06 to 36 and 36 to +36, I hope you know what are you doing. Besides, if you have text values in your T column and just want to change 36 to +36  only if 36 are the first two characters, you may use:

```
If Left(Range("T" & i), 2) = "36" Then Range("T" & i) = "+36" & Right(Range("T" & i), Len(Range("T" & i)) - 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using the `Replace` function alone.

From the [docs](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace_vba.php):

> Replace ( string1, find, replacement, [start, [count, [compare]]] )

The parameter `count` specifies, how many replacements should be made, not how far down the string the replacements should become effective.

Instead, go with something like this:

```
If InStr(Range("T" & i), "36") = 1 Then
    Range("T" & 1) = Replace(Range("T" & 1), "36", "+36")
End If
```